# Return ActiveRecord query as variable, not hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hash

I am doing an ActiveRecord find on a model as such

```
@foo = MyModel.find(:all, :select => 'year')
```

As you can see, I only need the year column from this, so my ideal output would be

```
["2008", "2009", "2010"]
```

Instead, though, I get an a hash of the models, with each one containing the year, as such:

```
[#<MyModel year: "2008">, #<MyModel year: "2009">, #<MyModel year: "2010">]
```

I can loop through it as such to convert it to my ideal output:

```
@years = []
for bar in @foo
    @years.push(bar.year)
end
```

but is there a way to retrieve this result to begin with? (i.e. without going through the extra processing?). If there is not, what is a more concise way to do this processing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
@foo = MyModel.find(:all, :select => 'year').map(&:year)
```

You also can call `.uniq()` on the result to remove duplicates.

```
@foo = MyModel.find(:all, :select => 'year').map(&:year).uniq
```

This is the short form for

```
@foo = MyModel.find(:all, :select => 'year').map{ |model| model.year }
```

This loops over the `MyModel` Array and crates a new array of the return values with in the block (`model.year`).

or even shorter code, but first calling everything from db:

```
@foo = MyModel.all.map(&:year)
```

Comment: Could you explain this please?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to instantiate models, you'd do it this way:

```
MyModel.connection.select_values("SELECT year FROM my_models")
```

This will return an Array of String objects. Then you can transform using Ruby tools as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to change every value in an array. Example:

```
@foo = MyModel.find(:all, :select => 'year').map { |model_object| model_object.year }
```

Comment: you need to put a dot between `'year')` and `map!`, and why do you use `map!`, `map` would just work fine here, because your assigning the result to a new variable